# Way to use sp in local database

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-server-ce

Work on VS2010 C# desktop application. 
My project connect with database.There  are many StoredProcedure and Tables,Now I want to use   Local database Database1.sdf.I  know how to use [Database1.sdf](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx) ,but problem is ,Here I cannot use Storedprocedure .Is there any way to use the sp on local database?If have any query plz ask.Thaks in advance.

Comment: It's a small project,i don't guess want to do.Use db really expensive for me and also for application owner .Now will you plz tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedures are not supported on SQL CE.

Neither are views, functions, UDT's, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Sql Express? I believe Sql Express supports SPs.

Comment: It's a small project,i don't guess want to do.Use db really expensive for me and also for application owner .Now will you plz tell me what to do?